# Android 3d carousel increase size of front image when we rotate

Tags: android, carousel

I am using http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel code and the following is my current output

when i rotate size of front image should be increased

**front image size has to be increased only when it comes to front position**

we can increase the size of the image using **getChildStaticTransformation** in **Carousel** class but i don't know how to do it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To just increase the size of the Selected Image change the Z coordinate in Carousal.java.

```
 private void Calculate3DPosition(CarouselItem child, int diameter, float angleOffset){

        angleOffset = angleOffset * (float)(Math.PI/180.0f);        

        float x = - (float)(diameter/2  * android.util.FloatMath.sin(angleOffset)) + diameter/2 - child.getWidth()/2;
        float z = diameter/2 * (1.0f - (float)android.util.FloatMath.cos(angleOffset));
        float y = - getHeight()/2 + (float) (z * android.util.FloatMath.sin(mTheta));

        child.setItemX(x);
        child.setItemZ(z-200);//Add how much size you want for Z axis.
        child.setItemY(y);

    }
```

Comment: If i add more images first image has to be increased not other images

Comment: Size is increased before first position